# Spring @Transactional is not working

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I am trying to use annotated TX Spring support.

**Application context XML:**

```
<?xml ...>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
        ...
    </bean>

    <bean id="repository" class="Repository">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Actual code:**

```
public class Repository {
    @Transactional
        public void save(Op op) {
            System.out.println("Transaction active:::: " + TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());

    ...
    }
}
```

**Calling code:**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/integration-context.xml"})
public class RepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private Repository repository;          

    @Test
    public void testRepositoryPersistence() {
        Op op = mock(Op.class);

        repository.save(op);
    }
}
```

And it gives **FALSE.**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show how you are calling the `save` method?

Comment: There isn't enough information here. _How_ are you interpreting the `@Transactional`? Using Spring proxies? Using Spring AOP? Using some form of weaving? Is the bean definitely created by Spring - i.e. it is being autowired somewhere? P.S. why use XML?

Comment: How are you loading the xml file, how are you calling the save method. Too little information here.

Comment: Extended my question.

Comment: Have you tried `<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class=true/>`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should add this in your configuration

```
<context:annotation-config/>

<tx:annotation-driven  transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>
```

add an interface on your RepositoryClass

```
public class Repository implements IRepository{
    @Transactional
        public void save(Op op) {
            System.out.println("Transaction active:::: " + TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());

    ...
    }
}
```

and this in your test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/integration-context.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = false)
public class RepositoryTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests{
    @Autowired
    private IRepository repository;          

    @Test
    public void testRepositoryPersistence() {
        Op op = mock(Op.class);

        repository.save(op);
    }
}
```

see [this](http://simplespringtutorial.com/springDeclarativeTransactions.html) tutorial.

Comment: +1 as this is _probably correct_. Worth noting that if the OP is using weaving (load or compile time) then the `interface` is not strictly speaking required.  Most certainly good practice though!

Comment: You don't really need to extend `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` only if you want your test to be the transactional boundary. It isn't a necessity for transactions to work. This setup basically renders `@Transactional` on this service useless (unless it would a REQUIRES_NEW or NEVER propagation level).