# Jersey + Spring = @Transactional not working

Tags: java, spring, junit, jersey, transactional

Hello I started an app with Jersey integrated with spring. To test my resources I´m using spring-test, like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:testApplicationContext.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false) //just to check if txmanager was working
public class UserDAOTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO dao;

    @Autowired
    private AuthorizationVerifyer verifyer;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        User user = new User(null, "name", "email", "pass", DateTime.now(), true);
        User savedUser = dao.save(user);

        assertNotNull(savedUser);
        assertNotNull(savedUser.getId());
    }
```

the problem is that all my tests break in the @Before method. Why? Because the User ID is null.
Lets go over my testApplicationContext.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sifionsolution.sig.authorization" />

    <!-- Inject properties -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>testDatabase.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${driver}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${user}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${password}"/>

        </bean>

   <!-- JPA EntityManagerFactory -->
    <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
          depends-on="flyway">
         <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceProvider">
            <bean class="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence" />
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.sifionsolution.sig.authorization.entity</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction manager  -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="flyway" class="org.flywaydb.core.Flyway" init-method="migrate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

My UserDAO class:

```
@Component
public class UserDAO {

    private GenericDAO<Long, User> dao;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager manager;

    @Transactional
    User save(User user) {
        return dao.save(user);
    }
...
```

Can some one help me to get this working?
thank you

**EDIT** Adding some of the Console logs:

```
13/10/14 14:16:50  INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315
Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:/D:/workspace/sig-authorization-jax-rs/bin/testApplicationContext.xml]
13/10/14 14:16:50  INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315
Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:/D:/workspace/sig-authorization-jax-rs/bin/testApplicationContext.xml]
13/10/14 14:16:50  INFO org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner:231
JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
13/10/14 14:16:50  INFO org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner:231
JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
13/10/14 14:16:50  INFO org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner:239
JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
13/10/14 14:16:50  INFO org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner:239
JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
13/10/14 14:16:50  INFO org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext:510
Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@162cc04e: startup date [Mon Oct 13 14:16:50 BRT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
13/10/14 14:16:50  INFO org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext:510
Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@162cc04e: startup date [Mon Oct 13 14:16:50 BRT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
13/10/14 14:16:50  INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer:172
Loading properties file from class path resource [testDatabase.properties]
13/10/14 14:16:50  INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer:172
Loading properties file from class path resource [testDatabase.properties]
13/10/14 14:16:50  INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor:141
JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
13/10/14 14:16:50  INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor:141
JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
13/10/14 14:16:50  INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:287
Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
13/10/14 14:16:50  INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:287
Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
13/10/14 14:16:51  INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory:603
Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@247fd5c5: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,tokenDAO,userDAO,tokenCreator,tokenValidator,authorizationVerifyer,authenticatedUserBuilder,permissionBuilder,roleWrapperBuilder,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,dataSource,emf,transactionManager,flyway,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
13/10/14 14:16:51  INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory:603
Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@247fd5c5: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,tokenDAO,userDAO,tokenCreator,tokenValidator,authorizationVerifyer,authenticatedUserBuilder,permissionBuilder,roleWrapperBuilder,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,dataSource,emf,transactionManager,flyway,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
13/10/14 14:16:51  INFO org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext:1042
Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@162cc04e: startup date [Mon Oct 13 14:16:50 BRT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
13/10/14 14:16:51  INFO org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext:1042
Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@162cc04e: startup date [Mon Oct 13 14:16:50 BRT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
13/10/14 14:16:51  INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory:444
Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@247fd5c5: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,tokenDAO,userDAO,tokenCreator,tokenValidator,authorizationVerifyer,authenticatedUserBuilder,permissionBuilder,roleWrapperBuilder,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,dataSource,emf,transactionManager,flyway,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
13/10/14 14:16:51  INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory:444
Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@247fd5c5: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,tokenDAO,userDAO,tokenCreator,tokenValidator,authorizationVerifyer,authenticatedUserBuilder,permissionBuilder,roleWrapperBuilder,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,dataSource,emf,transactionManager,flyway,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
13/10/14 14:16:51  INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:441
Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
13/10/14 14:16:51  INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:441
Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

**EDIT 2** After putting Transactional annotation in my test class I got:

```
Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@47b42535] to process 'after' execution for test: method [public void com.sifionsolution.sig.authorization.dao.UserDAOTest.shouldLogInActiveUser()], instance [com.sifionsolution.sig.authorization.dao.UserDAOTest@3f6df5a], exception [java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime.nullSafeSet(Ljava/sql/PreparedStatement;Ljava/lang/Object;ILorg/hibernate/engine/spi/SessionImplementor;)V]
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:522)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:755)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener$TransactionContext.endTransaction(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:591)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.endTransaction(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:297)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:192)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:406)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:91)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:92)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:513)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.sifionsolution.sig.authorization.entity.User entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:194)
```

**EDIT 3** GenericDAO

```
public class GenericDAO<PK, T> {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;
    private final Class<?> clazz;

    public GenericDAO(Class<?> clazz, EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T getById(PK pk) {
        return (T) entityManager.find(clazz, pk);
    }

    public T save(T entity) {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    }

    public void update(T entity) {
        entityManager.merge(entity);
    }

    public void delete(T entity) {
        entityManager.remove(entity);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<T> findAll() {
        return entityManager.createQuery(("FROM " + clazz.getName() + " obj")).getResultList();
    }

    public List<?> listByHql(String hql, HqlParameter... params) {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(hql);

        for (HqlParameter param : params)
            param.apply(query);

        return query.getResultList();
    }

    public Object uniqueResultByHql(String hql, HqlParameter... params) {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(hql);

        for (HqlParameter param : params)
            param.apply(query);

        try {
            return query.getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT 4** User entity code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_user")
@XmlRootElement
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    private String password;

    @Type(type = "org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
    private DateTime registration;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1)")
    private Boolean active;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<UserRole> userRoles;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<UserPermission> userPermissions;

    public User() {
    }
```

**EDIT 5** database

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name         | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password     | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email        | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| active       | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| registration | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

**EDIT 6** I changed this line:

```
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
```

And now I´m getting another exception:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime.nullSafeSet(Ljava/sql/PreparedStatement;Ljava/lang/Object;ILorg/hibernate/engine/spi/SessionImplementor;)V
    at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeSet(CustomType.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2602)
```

Comment: Have you ever seen this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25910635/3364187)?

Comment: Hello. I tried with DataSourceTransactionManager instead of JPATransactionManager also. Didnt work out. Also adding the <context:annotation-config/> doesnt cut it. Thank you for  the quick reply

Comment: Have you tried putting `@Transactional` on the test class?

Comment: Why do you not use `manager.persist(..);` within your UserDAO?

Comment: Alright Transactional in the test class got me somewhere @atamanroman. I´ll update the questions with the stacktrace. Xstian because I have a genericDAO with that logic encapsulated.

Comment: @MarcoNoronha if you use the Abstract Generic DAO pattern, i think that you should follow [this tutorial](http://insidecoding.com/2011/09/07/the-generic-dao-pattern-in-java-with-spring-3-and-jpa-2-0/), because there isn't reason to inject the EntityManger within DAO if you wrap its behaviour. Anyway, do you use the EntityManger into your encapsulated logic? Can you add the code of Entity?

Comment: @Xstian I´ll update the question to add the GenericDAO code :)

Comment: I just updated the answer again @Xstian. With my entity. thank you

Comment: @MarcoNoronha it is a pleasure to help you.. anyway, do you have NOT NULL field on your table?

Comment: Added the database columns for you to use @Xstian

Comment: I think that doesn't works the ID generation. Try to change IDENTITY in AUTO.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62991/discussion-between-marco-noronha-and-xstian).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summary of chat discussion

1. Adding @Transactional to test class
2. Adding transactionManager in @TransactionConfiguration

@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true) 
@Transactional 
//Test Class

Some forum suggest to use Jadira
with this annotation

```
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTimeWithZone")
```